# Convert string to java friendly string

Tags: java, powershell

Is there a native way to convert a given string into a java-friendly format in PowerShell? E.G. "\" needs to be replaced by the correct escape character sequence "\\", etc...

Answer (score 0):

When working with java from the powershell, I found it easier to run a linux based VM or a linux terminal. This solves all of the problems when directing to files from the arguments.

Comment: This does not directly solve the problem but it can be used to evade issues like this with future programs.